# How to run Laravel app when hosted through virtual host?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

Coming from CodeIgniter, I'd like to learn Laravel.
But I'm breaking my head 2 days over a (small) problem.

When I browse to the URL "laravel.app", It shows me the folder content instead of the index-page of Laravel.

These are my settings:

Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/public"
 ServerName laravel.app

 <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/public">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I added "Order allow, deny" and "Allow from all", else I get a 404.
What could be the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would verify public/index.php exists, and then try adding this line to your .htaccess file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

You may also want to tag this with "mamp". Hope you find it!

Comment: I added the "DirectoryIndex", now it goes to the index page, but as you can read from above, I receive raw content of the php.
When I remove the "Order allow,deny" and "Allow from all" I receive the following error: 403, You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: K. Found my problem, PHP5 was outcommend in my httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check application/config/application.php
for following entry?

'index' => 'index.php',

unless you have mod_rewrite for clean_urls setup